# How to extract max length row with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to extract row which is max in `Dataframe`.

In following case, I would like to get `id 2` row, because it includes max length 6 in B column `bbbbbb`.

```
|id|A   |B     |
|1 |abc |aaa   |
|2 |abb |bbbbbb|
|3 |aadd|cccc  |
|4 |aadc|ddddd |


|id|A   |B     |
|2 |abb |bbbbbb|
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get all columns filled by object (obviously strings) by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), get length with `max` per rows and last filter maximal by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for match all rows with maximal lengths:

```
s = df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max(axis=1)
#if no  missing values
#s = df.select_dtypes(object).applymap(len).max(axis=1)
df1 = df[s.eq(s.max())]
print (df1)
   id    A       B
1   2  abb  bbbbbb
```

Another idea for only first match by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), added `[]` for one row DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.loc[[df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max(axis=1).idxmax()]]
#if no missing values
#df1 = df.loc[[df.select_dtypes(object).applymap(len).max(axis=1).idxmax()]]


print (df1)
   id    A       B
1   2  abb  bbbbbb
```

Comment: The second one is a slightly modified my solution.

Comment: @MykolaZotko - yop, it is by columns for improvement performance, also max is per all data and added `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create the `DataFrame` with you example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
    "A ": {0: "abc", 1: "abb", 2: "aadd", 3: "aadc"},
    "B": {0: "aaa", 1: "bbbbbb", 2: "cccc", 3: "ddddd"}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then you can get the row where B is longer and then retrive that row with:

```py
# Index where B is longest
idx = df["B"].apply(len).idxmax()

# Get that row
df.iloc[idx, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find the maximal length per each row and then the row index with a maximal value:

```
df.loc[df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x.str.len().max(), axis=1).idxmax()]
```